# SQL Server Connection String Changes after Restore

Tags: sql-server

I just restored an SQL Server database and now I need to adjust my connection string and then I am off to the races.... The examples I googled look nothing like the connection string I need to adjust:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AbleCommerce" connectionString="Server=10.0.0.202;Database=db_com;Uid=admin@domain.com;Pwd=CHANGETHIS;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I look at Microsoft SQL Server I see this in my heading...I have not setup a password I am not aware of.

`MYNAME-PC\SQLEXPRESS\Databases\db_com\Tables`

Can someone help me out with adjusting this connection string?

I also see this in SQL Server `MYNAME-PC\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server 10.0.2531 - myname-PC\myname)`

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Is there any errors regarding this connectionstring?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just restored the database, as I see that the dbname (`db_com`) is still same and assuming that username and password is also not changed; your posted connection string should work just fine. anyway, your connection string should look like below.

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="AbleCommerce" connectionString="Server=MYNAME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db_com;
Uid=admin@domain.com;Pwd=CHANGETHIS;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using MSSQL Express,so you shall add instanse name to your connectionstring, then it will looks like this

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="AbleCommerce" connectionString="Server=10.0.0.202\SQLEXPRESS;  Database=db_com;Uid=admin@domain.com;Pwd=CHANGETHIS;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

if you are remotely accessing MSSQL Express, you shall also enable remote access in MSSQL Express